# How do you change form state to dirty on button press within a form in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a form in Angular with a form array where you can add or delete data. Currently, during marking a form as dirty, it does not include button press for deletion. Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
this.Form.get('control').markAsDirty();
this.Form.get('control').updateValueAndValidity();
```

where:

> Form : FormGroup and control (make it dirty) is control in Form